# Jade templates, adding to a head after extending a template

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, express, pug

I'm trying to learn jade/express by building a small web app that uses canvas to graph user data.

Currently, I'm just throwing together a Jade template, I've extended a previous template (one I call layout.jade) that includes general resources that are used on almost all pages.

My problem is that I want to extend the template, then ammend something to the head section for only that page and not others. I've been toying with it for a while and researching but can't find specific information on it.

Here's what I have

```
layout.jade
!!! 5
html
    head
        title EZgraph
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='stylesheets/ezgraph.css')
    body
    block content
    block scripts
```

And here's the template I'm working on

```
extends layout

head
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='stylesheets/barchartentry.css')
```

Is it possible to do something like this? Intuitively it seems to me like it should be but I'm just missing the mechanism to do it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I get into that very topic in this week's episode of a screencast series I do.  Here's a link to it: http://www.learnallthenodes.com/episodes/10-more-advanced-jade.

But, if you'd rather just have the answer, read on.  You can use more than one block in your template files.  In your case, you might make layout.jade look something like this:

```
layout.jade
!!! 5
html
    head
        title EZgraph
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='stylesheets/ezgraph.css')
        block extraHeader
    body
        block content
        block scripts
```

And then your template file:

```
extends layout

block extraHeader
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='stylesheets/barchartentry.css')
```

Note the matching extraHeader block calls in both the layout and the template.  That should get you going.

If you needed to add content to extraHeader from more than one template file in the same rendering, you can use `block append extraHeader` or the more succinct `append extraHeader`.  There's also a `prepend` variant if you want the additional content to appear at the beginning.

Edit: fixed some indenting.  Also, I indented `block content` and `block scripts` so that they would be children of `body`.  Lastly, even though that `block extraHeader` *will* be there on every call to your layout, unless your template gives it content to put in there, it won't inject anything else which meets your requirements, as I understand them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help. I'll check out your screencast if you're covering topics like this, I'll probably learn a lot!

Comment: thanks man, this was REALLY helpful. (but you should get a better mic ;) )

Comment: @user3787706 - heh, yeah, back then I thought I was supposed to speak into the top of my mic, and it turns out it was supposed to be the front.  Rookie mistake *facepalm*.  Glad it was useful. :)